# How can I insert a dynamic last row into a formula?

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I'm working with a clean sheet where I paste one column of dates with a varying number of rows. My goal is to show how many times each date shows up. However, every time I get to the last line I keep getting Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

Here is my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set startcell = Range("A1")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2").Formula = "=countif(A1:" & lastrow & ")"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your COUNTIF formula lacks the column specification for the end cell, perhaps `"=countif(A1:A" & lastrow & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF function takes 2 arguments (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34), not one as in your code. Also missed column letter in range. If you want to process N dates, you have to make N formulas COUNTIF.
Try this code (dates in column A from A1, formulas in column B):

```
Sub times()
    With ActiveSheet
        Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-1],RC[-1])"
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED! 4 WAYS

### High-level

- Countif formula is incorrect (missing: col label A + condition)
- Outlook: quick to fix, but requires loop for all dates
- Current method may be CPU/time-intensive for large lists

### Solutions A-D:

See Below (Links section), for google sheets (with full macro code, descriptions) for 4 solutions (3 macro based + 1 macro-free albeit dynamic soln). Briefly:

- A: output with correction to your code
- B: as for A, with for loop deployed
- C: VB code for much quicker implementation of for loop/.Function code
- D: macro-free variant (proposed/preferred)

---

**Screenshots**

[image: Output for A-D]

---

**Comparison table**

[image: Comparison of methods A-D]

---

**Links:**

- [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17GJcWG-JTCm1V3gYG69Sn6RsRzIcNDDyLYcnOSm0eCc/edit?usp=sharing)
- [VBA count and sumifs - Automate Excel](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/vba-countif-and-countifs-functions/)

---

**VB code (A-C)**

For completeness (same can be found in linked Google Sheet, typed - so macro-free / safe workbook):

```
Sub Macro_A():
  
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    cell = Range("a4").Address
    Range("B4").Value = "=countif(A1:" & "A" & lastrow & "," & cell & ")"
'    For i = 1 To lastrow - Range(cell).Row + 1
'        Range("B4").Offset(i - 1).Formula = "=countif(A1:" & "A" & lastrow & "," & Range(cell).Offset(i - 1).Address & ")"
'    Next
End Sub


Sub Macro_B():
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    start_time = Timer
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    cell = Range("a4").Address
'    Range("B4").Value = "=countif(A1:" & "A" & lastrow & "," & cell & ")"
    For i = 1 To lastrow - Range(cell).Row + 1
        Range("c4").Offset(i - 1).Formula = "=countif(A1:" & "A" & lastrow & "," & Range(cell).Offset(i - 1).Address & ")"
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Range("c3").End(xlDown).Offset(2).Value = Round(Timer - start_time, 2)
    
    
End Sub

Sub Macro_C():
    start_time = Timer
    Set Rng = Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In Rng
        cell.Offset(0, 3) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cell.Value)
    Next
    Range("d3").End(xlDown).Offset(2).Value = Round(Timer - start_time, 2)
End Sub
```

---

**Macro-free soln (D)**

1. Go to Formulas (ribbon), Name Manager:
   [image: Formulas, Name Manager toolbar]
2. In Name Manager window that apperas, click 'New...'
   [image: New named range selection]
3. Populate dialogue box as req. (modifying Sheet name and $A$4 starting cell as req.)
   [image: Name + dynamic range formula for new named range...]
4. Test your new dynamic range by clicking on upward arrow in bottom right hand corner (which should select dates in column A as depicted below)
   [image: 4a) Click upward facing arrow, bottom right-hand corner]

[image: 4b) Witness as all dates are automatically selected!]

5. Enter single formula in first cell of output range (here, cell D4)*:

[image: Single excel formula]

*Formulae (for convenience):*

- *range_countif*:

  =Sheet1!$A$4:OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-2,0,1,1)
- *Entry in cell D4*

  =COUNTIF(range_countif,range_countif)

*Notes: requires Office 360 for 'spill effect' (input as array formula with 'ctrl' + 'shift' + 'enter' otherwise).

Let me know if you have any further Qs.  Best of luck with your excel Spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to achieve. I use this formula to get the number of rows

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(IF(L2s!A2:A1009<>"",ROW(2:1011))))
```

Then I build a string from it

```
="L2s!A2:E"&D3
```

[image]

I love named ranges so I named the cell with the string built DynamicRangeL2s

Here is how I used the dynamic range in my formula (denormalize() is a custom function I wrote but could be any function) using the INDIRECT() function

```
=denormalize(INDIRECT(DynamicRangeL2s),INDIRECT(DynamicRangeSchedule),2,2,"right")
```

Here is a great article on Dynamic Ranges

https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/dynamic-named-ranges/